# How to find "P for trend" in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, odds-ratio

When I read some articles that used logistic regression, many of them report OR values (usually adjusted ones) plus the "p for trend."

Usually, "p for trend" is put when presenting a set of OR's related to dummy variables concerning an ordinal variable. For example: if y (0 / 1) is predicted using various IV's including educational level, then the education variable is a variable that would be fractured into dummy variables:
Secondary school: OR = 1
Diploma: OR = 1.12
Bachelor: OR = 1.70
Master: OR = 2.41
PhD: OR = 2.39
-------------> P for trend = .010

my question is how to get such p-value? I tried to find out in SPSS, but did not find such option.
I also made some search in R, and still found nothing.
I saw a link in a google search mentioning "p-for-trend" in SAS and Stata (and actually I didn't know what they are talking about, because I don't use the codes of these 2 software). Note: although Stata is user interface + coding software, I still couldn't find such option (for p-for-trend) in its user-interface options.

Comment: The default output of all this software includes p-values for the coefficients.  If you believe none of them are relevant, then please explain what you mean by "trend."

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you could test for trend in this case.

If you simply had one dichotomous variable and one ordinal variable, you could use a test designed for this situation, like the Cochran-Armitage test.

If you are using logistic regression, as you mention, you could code your ordinal independent variable as dummy variables. For the test of trend you would use planned (post-hoc) contrasts.  You might find contrasts that test for trend called "polynomial contrasts".  If you have five levels of your IV, you could test for a linear trend, quadratic, and so on, up to quartic.

The following document details some of this and has an example with code in SAS.

[,www.ndsu.edu/faculty/horsley/Polycnst.pdf](https://www.ndsu.edu/faculty/horsley/Polycnst.pdf)

Comment: Using a dummy encoding for education would produce a test of *heterogeneity* or some famous variant of the infamous test due to Pearson with test statistic given by $\sum_{i,j}(O_{ij} - E_{ij})^2 / E_{ij}$. The *trend* test considers, separately, whether higher levels of the input variable are associated with a directional effect in the response as measured by the OR. In this case, our logistic model would take the input, education, coded as 0 = lt HS, 1 = HS or GED, 2 = 4 year or equiv, 3 = post-grad nonterminal, and 4=terminal degree. The CA test is the score test for such a logistic model.